# multiple column in group by clause in datatable

Tags: c#

I have a data table contains 3 column count,memory,cores. Now I am trying to get sum of count group by memory and cores.

I am using this code :

```
var queryG = from row in dtFilterX.AsEnumerable()
                        group row by row.Field<string>("memory") into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = grp.Key,
                            sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("count"))
                        };
            foreach (var grp in queryG)
            {
                dtFilter.Rows.Add(grp.Id, grp.sum);
            }
```

I am not able to add core column in group by condition as I am new to LINQ.
Please help me.

Thanks
Gulrej

Answer (score 1):

For multiple columns in group by, **use anonymous type** (using new keyword):

```
group row by new 
             { 
               memoryCol = row.Field<string>("memory"), 
               coreCol = row.Field<string>("core")
              } into grp
```

Comment: var query = from row in dTable.AsEnumerable()
                       group row by new {row.Field<string>("memory"), row.Field<string>("core")} into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = grp.Key,
                            sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("id"))
                        }; Its giving me compilation error

Comment: @Gulrej, my bad, use names against row.Field<>, check my edited answer, you will not get any compiler error now